# Removing top.links url then re-adding link with custom label via local.xml

Tags: xml, magento

I'm attempting to remove the *My Account* link in top.links, then reintroduce them if the customer is logged in or out with custom labels without luck. Anyone got any ideas

```
<reference name="root">
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><position>10</position></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="top.links">
            <customer_logged_out>
                <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Register</label><url helper="customer/getRegisterUrl"/><title>Register</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
                <remove name="checkout_cart_link" />
            </customer_logged_out>

            <customer_logged_in>
                <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>My Account</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
            </customer_logged_in>

    </reference>
</reference>
```

Edit:

I'm using Magento 1.7. To clarify, removing the My Account link works using

`<action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><position>10</position></action>`

However I cannot add a new link using `method="addLink"`.

---

Solution:

I copied the customer.xml from /app/design/frontend/base/layout/ into my templates layout directory and added:

```
<customer_logged_in>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Log Out</label><url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/><title>Log Out</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>My Account</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
    </reference>
</customer_logged_in>
```

and

```
<customer_logged_out>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Register</label><url helper="customer/getRegisterUrl"/><title>Register</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
    </reference>
</customer_logged_out>
```

Ideally I'd prefer using local.xml to make these changes, but this works too.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the question. Could you clarify?

Comment: @ForceMagic First off, I'm using magento 1.7, what I want to do is remove the default **My Account** link, which is done successfully when using:

 `<action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><position>10</position></action>`

 However, if I want to add a new link using `method="addLink"`, the new link does not get added.

Comment: Ok that's great, post those informations inside your current question. You can do this by clicking on the "edit" link button. :) Add as much information as you can when you are posting question so it's easier for SO community to figure out how to solve your problem. Regards

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't need to put customer_logged_in node inside "top.links" reference.  Try this one:

```
<customer_logged_out>
    <reference name="top.links">
           <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Register</label><url helper="customer/getRegisterUrl"/><title>Register</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
           <remove name="checkout_cart_link" />
    </reference>
</customer_logged_out>

<customer_logged_in>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Log Out</label><url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/><title>Log Out</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
    </reference>
</customer_logged_in>
```

And also check this beautiful manual to understand fully how-to edit top.links inside local.xml:
   http://www.classyllama.com/development/magento-development/editing-magentos-top-links-the-better-way

Comment: I tried all of this before and it just didn't seem to work in local.xml, I ended up just copying customer.xml from the base theme and adding the links there. However it would still be nice to for me to get it to work in local.xml

Comment: put it outside any references, just <layout><customer_logged_in></customer_logged_in></layout>

Comment: Or just put the check in the template file?